# Хочу конвертировать FLAC в WAV

Tags: python, аудио

Пытаюсь конвертировать flac в wav:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
file = '/Volumes/Elements SE/Vinyl Collection/Paul McCartney - Flaming Pie (2CD Edition 2020)' \
       '/CD1/Paul McCartney - Flaming Pie - 2020 Remastered Album.flac'
audio_file = AudioSegment.from_file(file=file)
audio_file.export(file='/Volumes/Elements SE/Converter Output'
                       '/Paul McCartney - Flaming Pie - 2020 Remastered Album.wav', format='wav')
```

получаю вот что:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/MyHomeProject/audioconverter.py", line 6, in <module>
    audio_file = AudioSegment.from_file(file=file)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/MyHomeProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydub/audio_segment.py", line 685, in from_file
    info = mediainfo_json(orig_file, read_ahead_limit=read_ahead_limit)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/MyHomeProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydub/utils.py", line 274, in mediainfo_json
    res = Popen(command, stdin=stdin_parameter, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffprobe'
```

Comment: ну это здорово. а что вы сделали, чтобы не получать такой ошибки? в частности, что пишет документация на pydub по поводу наличия ffprobe?

Answer (score 1):

Необходима установка через brew install ffmpeg, тогда все заработает) @strawdog спасибо, что не даете сдаться без боя)))